# MySQL connection not available and werkzeug key error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, postman, werkzeug

I have a simple Flask app with a web form. When I submit the web form, and then upload the data to mysql, sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't. This is happening both locally and when I deploy to google cloud on a public url (`example.com`).

The form, located at `templates/auth/signup.html`, is

```
    <form method="POST" action="/signupSubmit">
            <label for="firstname">First name: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="firstname" id="firstname" required></input>
            <br /> <br />
            <label for="lastname">Last name: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" name="lastname" id="lastname" required></input>
            <br /> <br />
            <label for="phone">Phone number: </label>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="412-555-1234" name="phone" id="phone" required></input>
            <br /> <br />
            <label type="text" name="email" id="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="me@outlook.com" name="email" id="email" required></input>
            <br /> <br/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and the server logic within `main.py` is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os, mysql.connector, stripe

load_dotenv()

...

@app.route("/auth/signup", methods=['GET']) 
def signup():
    return render_template('auth/signup.html')

dataBase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=os.environ['DB_HOST'],
    password=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
    user=os.environ['DB_USER'],
    port=os.environ['DB_PORT'],
    database=os.environ['DB_DATABASE'],
    connection_timeout=3600
)

def saveSQLthenStripe(firstName, lastName, email, phone):
    query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" 
    vals = (firstName, lastName, email, phone) 
    cursorObject = dataBase.cursor()
    cursorObject.execute(query, vals) 
    dataBase.commit() 
    dataBase.close()
    thenStripe(firstName, lastName, email, phone)

@app.route("/signupSubmit", methods=['POST']) 
def collectForm():

    print(request.form['firstname'])
    if "firstname" in request.form:
        print("first name there")
    else:
        print("first name not there")
    fname = request.form['firstname'] 
    lname = request.form['lastname']
    email = request.form['email']
    phone = request.form['phone']
    saveSQLthenStripe(fname, lname, email, phone) 
    return render_template('auth/success.html', title="Submit successful")
```

An example of what just happened..
I ran the app locally with `python main.py`, submitted the form, it uploaded to mysql, no errors from the browser. The terminal printed

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 09:27:54] "GET /auth/signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -
test1
first name there
```

However, I went to postman, with the server still running, ran a `post` request to `http://localhost:8080/signupSubmit` with keys `firstname` `lastname` `phone` `email` and it returned this error

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this
        server could not understand.
        KeyError: &#39;firstname&#39;
```

while my terminal concurrently printed

```
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.        
KeyError: 'firstname'
```

Then, with server still running, I went back to the browser to `http://localhost:8080/auth/signup` and submitted the form with different info and received this error from the browser

```
OperationalError
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

with my terminal printing

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 09:29:29] "GET /auth/signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -
test2
first name there
```

I went to postman, again server still running, did post request and received same error as before

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this
        server could not understand.
        KeyError: &#39;firstname&#39;
```

with terminal printing same `KeyError: 'firstname'`.

On the live version (`example.com`) I am able to submit the form one time with no errors, but every successive attempt the browser returns with

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Dev tools says 500.

At one point in doing a different test, after submitting the form, my terminal printed (with full print statements):

```
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.        
KeyError: 'firstname'
first name there
last name there
email there
phone there
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
('somefirst', 'somelast', 'mail@gmail.com', '3333')
<mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at ***********>
<class 'mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection'>
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024 08:39:30] "POST /signupSubmit HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

directly contradicting that I did not have a `firstname`.

I ran `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` for mysql and it returned

```
Id    | User           | Host     | db   | Command  | Time  |  State                | Info 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5      event_scheduler  localhost  null   Daemon      6941326  Waiting on empty que  null
26362  rdsadmin         localhost  null   Sleep       7                              null
```

along with stuff from my internet company.

I'm confused about why mysql is not connected after one form submission, as I think that is what is ultimately causing the error.

Directory structure

```
myproject
|
|--env
|   |
|   +--Include
|   +--Lib         
|   +--Scripts
|   +--pyvenv.cfg
|
|--static
|--templates
|--.env 
|--.flaskenv 
|--.gitignore
|--app.yaml
|--main.py
|--requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I needed to put dataBase into saveSQLthenStripe. When I initially ran the app with `python main.py` it was creating the connection, but after that it was not.

So

```
def saveSQLthenStripe(firstName, lastName, email, phone):
    dataBase = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=os.environ['DB_HOST'],
        password=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
        user=os.environ['DB_USER'],
        port=os.environ['DB_PORT'],
        database=os.environ['DB_DATABASE'],
        connection_timeout=3600
    )
    query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" 
    ...
```

I still have not figured out the postman error, but my app is nonetheless working locally and in production (`example.com`).